# jQuery ajax post is sending request using get method on ipad chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, ipad

When this code runs on chrome on ipad, it ignores the type "POST" and sends the ajax request using the get method. Is it a compatibility issue? Seems like chrome doesnt support post ajax requests?

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajaxCall",
      data: sentData,
      success: success,
      dataType: "text",
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was testing the page on k-tunnnel/v-tunnel. I found out that the problem is becaouse of these sites. Without tunneling, my calls reaches the server properly.